# making an init: how exactly does the reboot command work?

Tags: systemd, init, systemctl

I'm trying to write an init, but can't figure out the reboot\poweroff thing.
apparently reboot is just a link to systemctl? (I'm using arch) So how does this work? `init poweroff` works and stuff, but `reboot`/`poweroff` just seems to be linked to `systemctl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many programs behave differently depending on the name with which they are called. Something like `systemctl` inspects the value of `argv[0]` and behaves differently if it is `reboot` vs if it is `systemctl`. You can see this taken to the extreme with [busybox](https://busybox.net), which is a single binary that provides almost an entire (minimal) userspace by symlinking all the commands to the single `busybox` binary.

You can do exactly the same thing with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [[ $0 =~ foo ]]; then
    echo "running foo action"
elif [[ $0 =~ bar ]]; then
    echo "running bar action"
else
    echo "running default action"
fi
```

Assuming this is `multicall.sh`, if we set things up like this:

```
ln -s multicall.sh foo
ln -s multicall.sh bar
```

And then see:

```
$ ./foo
running foo action
$ ./bar
running bar action
$ ./multicall.sh
running default action
```

For `systemctl` in particular, the logic is implemented [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/5c8e19cc1cfc58cd65a8bfe0fea4ea16ea513dcf/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L1003):

```
int systemctl_dispatch_parse_argv(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        assert(argc >= 0);
        assert(argv);

        if (invoked_as(argv, "halt")) {
                arg_action = ACTION_HALT;
                return halt_parse_argv(argc, argv);

        } else if (invoked_as(argv, "poweroff")) {
                arg_action = ACTION_POWEROFF;
                return halt_parse_argv(argc, argv);

        } else if (invoked_as(argv, "reboot")) {
                if (kexec_loaded())
                        arg_action = ACTION_KEXEC;
                else
                        arg_action = ACTION_REBOOT;
                return halt_parse_argv(argc, argv);
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: That's a great explanation. Thanks a lot!